# Create a view using a pre-made function for GST amount and Total Price (price + GST)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, view, sql-server-2014

I am struggling with calling a function with in a view to create a list of sales details including a column for GST amount and the total sale price (original price plus GST) for each individual sale.

Here is the function I have created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ReturnTaxedPrice

    @ProductID int,
    @GST float,
    @GSTPrice float output

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Price float
    SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)
    SET @GSTPrice = @Price * (1 - @GST)
END
```

And here is the view I would like to use that function in to add two columns at the end of the table to display the GST amount and total price amount (original price plus GST) for each sale:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_SaleDetails
AS
SELECT 
    Sales.SaleNo, 
    Sales.SaleDate, 
    Customer.FirstName, 
    Customer.LastName,
    Category.Category, 
    Products.ProductDescription, 
    Type.Type, 
    Products.Year, 
    Products.Price

FROM Category JOIN Customer ON Category.CategoryID = Customer.CategoryID
    JOIN Sales ON Customer.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
    JOIN SalesProducts ON Sales.SaleNo = SalesProducts.SaleNo
    JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = SalesProducts.ProductID
    JOIN ProductType ON Products.ProductID = ProductType.ProductID
    JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = ProductType.TypeID
```

Comment: You have a `PROCEDURE`, not a [`FUNCTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Procedures are standalone blocks of code and cannot be "composed" into larger queries. Also, are you sure that your GST calculation is correct?

Comment: You need to change our `PROCEDURE` to a `FUNCTION` and add at the end the statement `return @GSTPrice`. Note that in SQL SERVER a function cannot have OUT parameters. As such, you also need to remove `@GSTPrice` from the function's signature.

Answer (score 0):

You want a function, not a procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.sp_ReturnTaxedPrice (
    @ProductID int,
    @GST float
) RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Price float;

    SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID);

    SET @GSTPrice = @Price * (1 - @GST);

    RETURN(@GSTPrice);
END;
```

Then, you can do:

```
select . . .
       dbo.sp_ReturnTaxedPrice(@ProductID, @GST)
. . .
```

Now some comments:

- Putting this logic in a user-defined function (or stored procedure) adds a lot of overhead.  You should just put the arithmetic in the code.
- `float` is not the right data type for monetary values.  Use `MONEY` or `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC`.
- If you don't understand why, learn about fixed-point versus floating-point types.